# Coloring background

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newtheoremstyle{problemstyle}
        {12pt}
        {8ex}
        {}
        {}
        {\bfseries}
        {}
        {0.5em}
        {}
\theoremstyle{problemstyle}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill[blue!10!white] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-6cm)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{problem}
When the polynomial $P(x)$ is divided by $(x-1), (x+1), (x-2)$, it gives the remainders $2, 6, 3$, respectively. Determine:

\begin{displaymath}
\frac{P(x)}{(x-1)(x+1)(x-2)}
\end{displaymath}
\end{problem}


\paragraph*{Solution}
We are given that,
\begin{align*}
P(x)&=(x-1)\cdot Q_1(x)+2\\[1ex]
P(x)&=(x+1)\cdot Q_2(x)+6\\[1ex]
P(x)&=(x-2)\cdot Q_3(x)+3 \tag{1}
\end{align*}

And we know that,
\begin{displaymath}
P(x)=(x-1)(x+1)(x-2)\cdot Q_4(x)+ax^2+bx+c \tag{2}
\end{displaymath}

Plugging in the values from (1) into (2), we have:
\begin{displaymath}
\left.
\begin{aligned}
    P(1)=2&=a+b+c\\[1ex]
    P(-1)=6&=a-b+c\\[1ex]
    P(2)=3&=4a+2b+c
\end{aligned}
\right\}\implies a=1, b=-2, c=3
\end{displaymath}

Thus,
\begin{displaymath}
\frac{P(x)}{(x-1)(x+1)(x-2)}=x^2-2x+3
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I am trying color the background from the top left point of the page (actual whole page) to some space below right of a given problem. In the above example, the calculation is done manually. What would be a good way achieve it such that it would work for any given length of content?

Comment: You could use `tikzmark` library to put a node right after your problem, and use it into your `tikzpicture` to colour the top of the page.

Comment: The background should start at the top left point of the physical sheet of paper?

Comment: @Bernard Yes. Edited the question.

Comment: Load `\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}`. Then `\fill[blue!10!white] (current page.north west) rectangle ( $ (pic cs:prob1) +(\paperwidth,0) $ );` and `\end{displaymath}\tikzmark{prob1}` to mark the second coordinate in the text. `\paperwidth` ensures that the rectangle always goes beyond the margin. The calculation can be made more accurate if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind this solution is to use the `shipout/background` hook and to define a command that calls `\tikzmark` and define the second coordinate of the rectangle. (The code definitely needs improvement, but my skills stop there.)

```
\newcounter{rectmark}
\newcommand{\printrectangle}{\stepcounter{rectmark}
  \gdef\mynode{pic cs:\therectmark}\tikzmark{\therectmark}}
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill[blue!10!white] (current page.north west) rectangle 
    ( $ (\mynode) +(\paperwidth,0) $ );
  \end{tikzpicture}
\gdef\mynode{0,0}}
```

Then in the text you will only need

```
\printrectangle
```

to have a rectangle from the top left point of the page to the coordinate of the actual `\printrectangle` command plus `\paperwidth` to reach (in fact, overcome) the right margin: `+(\paperwidth,0)`.

`\gdef\mynode{0,0}` resets the command to print nothing (in fact a zero size rectangle) after every `\printrectangle`. Without this, all pages would have a rectangle of height equal to the ordinate of the last `\printrectangle`.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}

\newtheoremstyle{problemstyle}
        {12pt}
        {8ex}
        {}
        {}
        {\bfseries}
        {}
        {0.5em}
        {}
\theoremstyle{problemstyle}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}

\newcounter{rectmark}
\newcommand{\printrectangle}{\stepcounter{rectmark}
  \gdef\mynode{pic cs:\therectmark}\tikzmark{\therectmark}}
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill[blue!10!white] (current page.north west) rectangle 
    ( $ (\mynode) +(\paperwidth,0) $ );
  \end{tikzpicture}
\gdef\mynode{0,0}}

\begin{document}


\begin{problem}
When the polynomial $P(x)$ is divided by $(x-1), (x+1), (x-2)$, it gives the remainders $2, 6, 3$, respectively. Determine:

\begin{displaymath}
\frac{P(x)}{(x-1)(x+1)(x-2)}
\end{displaymath}\printrectangle
\end{problem}

\paragraph*{Solution}
We are given that,
\begin{align*}
P(x)&=(x-1)\cdot Q_1(x)+2\\[1ex]
P(x)&=(x+1)\cdot Q_2(x)+6\\[1ex]
P(x)&=(x-2)\cdot Q_3(x)+3 \tag{1}
\end{align*}

And we know that,
\begin{displaymath}
P(x)=(x-1)(x+1)(x-2)\cdot Q_4(x)+ax^2+bx+c \tag{2}
\end{displaymath}

%\clearpage

Plugging in the values from (1) into (2), we have:
\begin{displaymath}
\left.
\begin{aligned}
    P(1)=2&=a+b+c\\[1ex]
    P(-1)=6&=a-b+c\\[1ex]
    P(2)=3&=4a+2b+c
\end{aligned}
\right\}\implies a=1, b=-2, c=3
\end{displaymath}

Thus,
\begin{displaymath}
\frac{P(x)}{(x-1)(x+1)(x-2)}=x^2-2x+3
\end{displaymath}

\begin{problem}
When the polynomial $P(x)$ is divided by $(x-1), (x+1), (x-2)$, it gives the remainders $2, 6, 3$, respectively. Determine:

\begin{displaymath}
\frac{P(x)}{(x-1)(x+1)(x-2)}
\end{displaymath}
\end{problem}

\paragraph*{Solution}
We are given that,
\begin{align*}
P(x)&=(x-1)\cdot Q_1(x)+2\\[1ex]
P(x)&=(x+1)\cdot Q_2(x)+6\\[1ex]
P(x)&=(x-2)\cdot Q_3(x)+3 \tag{1}
\end{align*}

And we know that,
\begin{displaymath}
P(x)=(x-1)(x+1)(x-2)\cdot Q_4(x)+ax^2+bx+c \tag{2}
\end{displaymath}

Plugging in the values from (1) into (2), we have:
\begin{displaymath}
\left.
\begin{aligned}
    P(1)=2&=a+b+c\\[1ex]
    P(-1)=6&=a-b+c\\[1ex]
    P(2)=3&=4a+2b+c
\end{aligned}
\right\}\implies a=1, b=-2, c=3
\end{displaymath}\printrectangle

Thus,
\begin{displaymath}
\frac{P(x)}{(x-1)(x+1)(x-2)}=x^2-2x+3
\end{displaymath}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `eso-pic` to add a coloured rule of the relavant width and  height:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newtheoremstyle{problemstyle}
        {12pt}
        {8ex}
        {}
        {}
        {\bfseries}
        {}
        {0.5em}
        {}
\theoremstyle{problemstyle}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}

\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\AtPageUpperLeft{\color{blue!10}\rule[-1em]{\dimexpr\textwidth + 2em}{1em}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill[blue!10!white] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-6cm)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{problem}
When the polynomial $P(x)$ is divided by $(x-1), (x+1), (x-2)$, it gives the remainders $2, 6, 3$, respectively. Determine:

\begin{displaymath}
\frac{P(x)}{(x-1)(x+1)(x-2)}
\end{displaymath}
\end{problem}


\paragraph*{Solution}
We are given that,
\begin{align*}
P(x)&=(x-1)\cdot Q_1(x)+2\\[1ex]
P(x)&=(x+1)\cdot Q_2(x)+6\\[1ex]
P(x)&=(x-2)\cdot Q_3(x)+3 \tag{1}
\end{align*}

And we know that,
\begin{displaymath}
P(x)=(x-1)(x+1)(x-2)\cdot Q_4(x)+ax^2+bx+c \tag{2}
\end{displaymath}

Plugging in the values from (1) into (2), we have:
\begin{displaymath}
\left.
\begin{aligned}
    P(1)=2&=a+b+c\\[1ex]
    P(-1)=6&=a-b+c\\[1ex]
    P(2)=3&=4a+2b+c
\end{aligned}
\right\}\implies a=1, b=-2, c=3
\end{displaymath}

Thus,
\begin{displaymath}
\frac{P(x)}{(x-1)(x+1)(x-2)}=x^2-2x+3
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

[image]